# Populate cassandra after Docker-compose finishes

Tags: docker, cassandra, sh, docker-compose

Here's my `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  cassandra:
    container_name: cassandra
    image: cassandra:3.10
    ports:
      - 9142:9042
    volumes:
      - $PWD/src/database/migrations:/migrations
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./src/database/migrations:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=leonardo
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1
```

And a shell script `bootstrap.sh` to start:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
docker-compose -f $PWD/docker-compose.yaml down
docker-compose -f $PWD/docker-compose.yaml up -d
```

This is working and fires up the stack.
Now I'd like to add a keyspace to Cassandra, however, below this line throws an error:

```
docker-compose -f $PWD/docker-compose.yaml exec cassandra /bin/sh -c $'cqlsh cassandra -e "CREATE KEYSPACE mykeyspace WITH replication = {\'class\': \'SimpleStrategy\', \'replication_factor\': \'1\'}  AND durable_writes = true;"'
```

> Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'172.18.0.2':
>   error(111, "Tried connecting to [('172.18.0.2', 9042)]. Last error:
>   Connection refused")})

Cassandra has probably not initialised yet.
What's a good approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to execute a command in Cassandra in your `bootstrap.sh` script just after starting the containers, the Cassandra server won't have the time to start.

A simple solution would be to wait a few seconds in your script before executing the command, using an [until loop](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_03.html):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
docker-compose -f $PWD/docker-compose.yaml down
docker-compose -f $PWD/docker-compose.yaml up -d
until docker-compose -f $PWD/docker-compose.yaml exec cassandra /bin/sh -c "cqlsh cassandra -e 'show version'";
do
  docker-compose -f $PWD/docker-compose.yaml exec cassandra /bin/sh -c $'cqlsh cassandra -e "CREATE KEYSPACE mykeyspace WITH replication = {\'class\': \'SimpleStrategy\', \'replication_factor\': \'1\'}  AND durable_writes = true;"'
done
```

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick. Instead of waiting 30 seconds, is it possible to make it event based? We have no guarantee that Cassandra is ready after 30 sec - it's just an assumption (albeit a good one).

Comment: I've updated my answer, by replacing "sleep" with an "until loop", which make it work with any boot duration.